# Call less constrained functionally equivalent function

Tags: c++, overloading, c++20, c++-concepts

Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A;

template<class T>
concept HasParent = std::is_convertible_v<typename T::parent*, A*>;

struct A{};

struct B : A { using parent = A; };

template<class T>       int foo(T*) { return 1; }

template<HasParent T>   int foo(T*)
{
  // call the other one?
  return 2;
}

int main()
{
  B b;
  std::cout << foo(&b) << std::endl; // displays 2
  return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to call the general `foo<T>(T*)` function from `foo<HasParent T>(T*)`?

*(this is a (functional) example, but I can link the complete code on github)*

Comment: So you want to call the general version with the `T*` passed to the `HasParent T` version?

Comment: What you can do is to write you general `foo` that way `template<class T, bool F=false>       int foo(T*) { return 1; }`, and then you could do `foo<T,false>(t)`, but I hope that is not the only way how this can be solved.

Comment: @t.niese, It's definitely not the only way since there's always the relatively clean option of factoring out the common part into a separate function.

Comment: @chris sure that is a way how to solve the requirement of calling the generalized function from the specialized (and might be the better way), but it wouldn't answer the question, if/how it would be possible.

Comment: @chris except that the common part is the whole other function, the overload is just user to call the same method with the parent, recursively and if available

Comment: @t.niese that's an idea, but as you figured out, I'd like to know if it's possible otherwise first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to call the general `foo<T>(T*)` function from `foo<HasParent T>(T*)`?

You need *some* way to differentiate between the two functions in order to do this.

For example:

```
template <typename T>               void foo(T);
template <typename T> requires true auto foo(T) -> int;
```

The second one is obviously more constrained than the first, for all `T`, so `foo(42)` calls the second. But, you *can* differentiate between the two:

```
auto unconstrained = static_cast<void(*)(int)>(foo);
```

Here, the constrained function template returns `int` so it's not a viable candidate and we get the unconstrained one instead.

In your example, both return `int`, so this particular trick doesn't work. But the key is that you need *some* way to differentiate the two templates.

A better way is probably:

```
template <typename T, std::monostate M = {}>
void foo(T);

template <typename T> requires true
void foo(T arg) {
    foo<T, std::monostate{}>(arg); // calls the unconstrained one
}
```

Using `monostate` here is kinda cute since it doesn't actually change the number of template instantiations (there's only one `monostate`... ). `foo(42)` calls the second, which calls the first. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8Lpp28).

But it might be better to just add a new function and have both the unconstrained and constrained version of the function template invoke that one (in the sense that it's arguably less cryptic than the `monostate` approach).

Comment: Should we mention `template<class T> int foo(T*) { if constexpr (HasParent<T>) { } else {} }` in this answer? I'm a big fan of not overloading when I can get away with it.

Comment: @Casey that is actually a good idea, as it would solve my problem too in fact ;-)

Comment: @Casey Maybe? Thought it'd be more interesting to focus on the specific problem, and I kinda like the monostate template parameter :-)